# My docker container's crontab doesn't seem to be running

Tags: docker, cron

I'm fairly new to Docker so please bear with me:

I have a collection of 5 java applications that I'm trying to run inside a docker container (via cronjobs inside the container).

I've created my Dockerfile and a docker-compose file as well.  I'm able to launch my docker container and I'm able to manually run my applications inside the container.  The problem is, it doesn't seem to be running my stuff via the cron.  To test, I added a cron entry to echo hello world to a file every minute.  It doesn't seem to run.  Here are my files:

Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
ENV LANG C.UTF-8
ENV TZ=EST
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive 
RUN mkdir -p /wrds/ingesters/logs

WORKDIR /wrds/ingesters

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y  \
    tzdata \
    apt-utils \
    cron \
    default-jdk \
    bash \
    postgresql \
    bsd-mailx \
    postfix \
    vim

COPY *.jar /wrds/ingesters/
COPY run* /wrds/ingesters/
COPY *.properties /wrds/ingesters/

ADD ingester_cron /etc/cron.d/root
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/root
RUN touch /var/log/cron.log
RUN crontab /etc/cron.d/root

RUN mkfifo /var/spool/postfix/public/pickup

RUN echo 'alias ll="ls -la"' >> ~/.bashrc
RUN echo 'stty erase ^H' >> ~/.bashrc

CMD cron -L15 && tail -f /var/log/cron.log
```

docker-compose.yml (anything in all caps is edited out by me for security issues)

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  wrds_hylo_db_ingesters:
    image: HOSTNAME/wrds/CONTAINERNAME
    container_name: CONTAINERNAME
    restart: always
    env_file: env.dev-v2
    volumes:
      - /ingester_logs:/wrds/ingesters/logs
    pid: host
```

ingester_cron

```
0 17 * * 1 root /wrds/ingesters/run_script1
0 20 * * 1 root /wrds/ingesters/run_script2
0 23 * * 1 root /wrds/ingesters/run_script3
0 2 * * 2 root /wrds/ingesters/run_script4
* * * * * root echo "Hello World" >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1
```

When I run my docker container and ssh in, I get the following:

```
root@1b0d719feada:/var/log# service cron status
 * cron is running
```

```
crontab -l
0 17 * * 1 root /wrds/ingesters/run_script1
0 20 * * 1 root /wrds/ingesters/run_script2
0 23 * * 1 root /wrds/ingesters/run_script3
0 2 * * 2 root /wrds/ingesters/run_script4
* * * * * root echo "Hello World" >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you take a look at the logs. Maybe you can see more of what your crons are doing.

Cron: `*/3 * * * * YOUR-CRON_BLABLA > /dev/stdout` logs to the container output

ex.: `docker-compose logs -f`

I load my cron jobs like this:

```
COPY ./MY-CRON-FILE.cron /

RUN crontab /tmp/MY-CRON-FILE.cron

...
```

Depending on the application also sometimes with a certain user:

```
RUN crontab -u MY-USER /MY-CRON-FILE.cron
```